# Fill Tasks "Subject" field with API name

Tags: api, tasks

I'm creating tasks from an internal tool though a REST integration, and wanted to rely on API names to set Subject values.

However the Subject that's input is actually the API name, and not its label.

Do you know if it's normal behavior or if there's a way for me to work around this ? I know that Subject is a combobox that kind of behaves like a text field, but then I'm wondering why they still allow to change the API name of associated values if we can't use them?

Thanks a lot for the help !

[[image: Screenshot of Subject field values and API names[1]]

Comment: Why is the integration passing api values with underscores? Can it not pass normal text strings with spaces? I typically don't mess with how Salesforce sets their API names based on labels (which in this case is identical to the label).

Comment: Hi @KrisGoncalves, Thanks for your answer. We wanted to use API names to be able to update labels in Salesforce without needing to rework the integration set up.

Comment: Are you able to post the code you're doing through rest integration? What happens when you do try to use the API name to set the "Subject" value on creation? Is there an error or does Subject not come through at all?